# Blogger widget not working with my own link to the .js file

Tags: java, blogger

I am using a Blogger widget for random posts, and I noticed that sometimes it's not working. I figured out that there was a problem with getting the .js file from the link given in the script. I copied the link, pasted it into the browser, and I got a message that too many users wanted to access the file. So, the next time it worked again, I downloaded the .js file to my PC, I uploaded it to my Google Drive, changed the ID in the link to the ID of my file – but it doesn't work. When I paste the whole modified link to the browser, it downloads the .js file, but if it's in the code, the widget will not work. Any ideas? 
(This is the original script below)

```
<script numberofposts="5" label="none" posttitle="left" titlesize="9" 
titlefont="'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif" titlecolor="#cece00" textsize="0" 
textcolor="#333333" textfont="'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif" 
thumbnail="left" thumbnailsize="80" thumbnailrounding="8"
nothumbnail="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-go-1bJQKzCY/XIpRVUCKeCI/AAAAAAAAAQM/YUdYK3hEkcIFwcz0r-T2uErre0JOJWnrwCLcBGAs/s1600/no-image.png" 
postinfo="left" postauthor="none" publishdate="none" numofcomments="none" postcategories="none" 
excerptlength="0" async src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1845xMVCmJyzmji4NPoJzeu7QgNVn0P-s"></script>
```